# How can I control the order of the fields

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have just started trying backpack and think it's fantastic! The only issue I am finding (which may well be my fault) is as follows:

I have added a table based select in my DealerCrudController.php

CRUD::field('country_id')->type('select')->entity('country')->attribute('name')->model('App\Models\Country');

Problem - it appears as the first field in the forms, when I want it to appear last!

So my questions are:

What controls the position in the form?

Is there any way I can control the order of the fields?

(I have tried adding ->afterColumn('address_1') but this didn't appear to have any effect)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mistyped `afterColumn()`, it should be `afterField()`.

Here are the docs for that operations: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-api#create-update-operations

Cheers